# How can I load reactive data to multiselect component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to use this library https://github.com/vueform/multiselect, but whenever I try to load fetched data, nothing shows up in there, but for e.g when I do `{{ testData }}` I see the value in html. Can anyone advice me how can I fix this?

Works:
`<Multiselect :options="['test']" />`

Doesn't work:

```html
<Multiselect :options="testData" />
```

in my setup()

```js
  const testData = computed(() => {
      return [
        {
          name: "Test"
        }
      ]
    })

return { testData }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above I assume it should be an array, so try this

```
 const testData = computed(() => {
      return [{ name: "Test"}]
    })

return { testData }
```

and add the below change in template

```
<Multiselect :options="testData" track-by="name" label="name"/>
```

Modified on request:

If you wanna show the entire object then you can follow the below example

```
 const testData = computed(() => {
      return [
        { name: 'Vue.js', id: 'vue' },
        { name: 'Angular', id: 'angular' }
      ]
 })

return { testData }
```

and add a method called `nameWithId` with the below content.
**Note**: I have given it based on Vue2 syntax, pls change the syntax that matches to Vue3

```
nameWithId({ name, id }) {
      return `${name} — [${id}]`
    }
```

then with the below changes in your template

```
<Multiselect v-model="selectedValue" :options="testData" :custom-label="nameWithId" placeholder="Select one" label="name" track-by="name"/>
```

Reference doc: https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-getting-started

Comment: Do you might know, if I pass an object that has an id field as well, and I v-model it, in my html it only displays the name, can I make it show entire value of object somehow?

Comment: Yes you can do it, pls check the additional details added in the answer